# How to add custom properties to dynamically (programmatically) created controls in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, dynamic, firemonkey

In the app that I am building I am adding controls dynamically to `TFramedScrollbox` control on Form.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
pnlNew: TFlowLayout;
pnlNew := TFlowLayout.Create(sbMain);
pnlNew.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
pnlNew.ClipChildren := True;

pnlNew.Parent := sbMain;
```

And this code is working as expected.

But I want to add dynamic properties like OrgHeight, CreateOrder, PrevControl, etc. to this programmatically created control.

How to do this?

TIA

Comment: If you want to add new properties to any control whether it is created statically (during design-time) or dynamically (at runtime) you will have to make derived class from the wanted control that will contain these additional properties. For design-time that new class needs to be registered in Delphi for new properties to be visible in object inspector. But for runtime this will not be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an "interposer class" just above your form definition, like this:

```
TFlowLayout = class(FMX.Layouts.TFlowLayout) // note fully qualified name of the class we inherit from
private
  OrgHeight: single;
  //... other properties you want to add
end;

TForm36 = class(TForm)
  sbMain: TFramedScrollBox;
  Button1: TButton;
  //...
```

Strictly speaking, in this case, when you create the instance dynamically at runtime, you don't really need to define the "interposer class" before the form definition. You would have to, if you would have an instance of the `TFlowLayout` on your form already at design time.

From now on, the `TFlowLayout` you instantiate on your form has those added properties, and you can write e.g.:

```
pnlNew := TFlowLayout.Create(sbMain);
pnlNew.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
pnlNew.ClipChildren := True;
pnlNew.Parent := sbMain;
pnlNew.OrgHeight := pnlNew.Height;
pnlNew.Height := 150;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking what your code example here is adding are just fields not properties. But yes using "interposer class" is one way of doing this. I personally avoid them as they can cause some problems esxecially if you are accessing such classes from other units as unit containing "interposer class" needs to be added to the end of the uses list. Not to mention that the added functionality from "interposer class" is not available to any derived class. This could then cause confusion to other programmers that go extending your class and then wonder why some functionality is simply missing.

Comment: By the way Žarko Gajić has a neat little article on [interposer classes](https://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/delphi-interceptor-classes-tbutton-classtbutton/)

Comment: @SilverWarior, Thank you very much for this article. I managed to solve my problem!!

Comment: @Tom Brunberg you are also right in suggesting how to add a Property to a control.